# Facebook Like Box not working for FB Page

Tags: html

I am trying to create a Like Box for this Facebook page:  https://www.facebook.com/westierescue.austin
to put on their website.
I am unable to get the page to work in your Facebook developers site.

Can you please test this and advise how to generate a Like Box for this page?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What have you tried? "unable to get the page to work" isn't much to go on...

Comment: It might help you to get an answer if you read through the help center and then rephrase your question. In particular http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: As far as I know the Like Box does not work with personal profile page. You need to create a fan page or an app.

Answer (score 1):

thats not a facebook "page", its a  facebook "user", users dosn't have liks, you need to convert the "user" to a "page" first.

https://www.facebook.com/help/175644189234902/